# Add Jenkins job parameter to all jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

All of my Jenkins jobs need the same two parameters added to them. I have way too many jobs to configure by hand in a reasonable amount of time.

Is there a way to add a job parameter to them all at once? Even one folder at a time would save me a great deal of effort. Currently, hacking the config.xml files seems faster than adding them one by one via the UI.

Again, these parameters **do not exist yet**, so unless Configuration Slicing has some hidden feature, I am not sure how to accomplish this.

TIA for any answers!

Comment: What type of jobs (freestyle, pipeline ..) are your jobs? Do they use same scripts?

Comment: They are pipelines.  Some share the same pipeline script, but we are maintaining about 20 of them due unique environmental issues.  Just looking to add a couple of string parameters too all jobs, so our supporting groovy helpers/scripts can use them to configure our environments correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of following possibilities. 
For **declarative pipelines** the `parameters` directive could be added into the pipeline scripts.

```
parameters {
  string(name: 'FIRST_ PARAM', defaultValue: 'Test')
  string(name: 'SECOND_PARAM', defaultValue: 'Test2')
}
```

If the jobs are **scripted pipelines** you could add

```
properties(
[
    parameters(
        [string(defaultValue: 'Test', name: 'FIRST_PARAM'),
         string(defaultValue: 'Test2', name: 'SECOND_PARAM')]
        )
]
)
```

The jobs need to be built once in order for parameters to be visible.
Another possibility would be to iterate over all jobs and add parameters

```
<hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
  <parameterDefinitions>
    <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
      <name>FIRST_PARAM</name>
      <description></description>
      <defaultValue>Test</defaultValue>
      <trim>false</trim>
    </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
  </parameterDefinitions>
</hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
```

to `properties` tag in `config.xml` of the jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! It would take longer to add the properties to the pipelines and run every job to pick up the new params than to manually add them via the UI due to the sheer number of jobs.  Looks like hacking the config.xml files might be the right solution.